# NullPointerException while initializing an Object reference - Junit test method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

I have a method 'validateFile()' which needs to be unit tested.The method returns a reference of a user defined type. This reference is set with a value returned from another method 'M'.This method 'M' is mocked and returns the mocked result.However setting the reference throws a NullPointerException.
The code is as shown :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ExcelValidations.class, MiscellaneousService.class})    
class TestClass(){

@Test
public void sampleTest(){
  ExcelSheetIngestion excelSheetIngestion = new ExcelSheetIngestion();
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(MiscellaneousService.class);
  Mockito.when(MiscellaneousService.getRandomString()).thenReturn("mockedString123");

  FileResponse response = excelSheetIngestion.validateFile(streamTest);
  Assert.assertNotEquals("null",response.getBatchId());

}

class ExcelSheetIngestion(){

  @Inject 
  FileUploadResponse  response;
  //The method to be tested
  public FileResponse validateFile(){

  String randomString = MiscellaneousService.getRandomString();//mocked and return mockedString123
  response.setBatchId(randomString);//throws exception at this point
  response.setError(errorList); 
  return response;
  }
}
```

Any clue as to where I have gone wrong would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like in `validateFile()` you are using `response` *field* but we don't see when you initialize it. In `sampleTest` you created `FileResponse response = ...` but this creates *local variable*.

Comment: oops,I just edited my code.It should have been FileResponse in both the methods. I have added a comment where the exception is thrown

Comment: Where are you initializing excelSheetIngestion? Or streamTest for that matter?

Comment: Its initialized within the Test method. Edited the code just now, sorry.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(MiscellaneousService.class)` annotations on your test class? [See example here.](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#a-full-example-for-mocking-stubbing--verifying-static-method)

Comment: I have added these annotation s and the mocking has no problem